# Can Magento 2 use manufacturer to require min product?

Tags: magento2

I try to create an ecommerce with products of many company.

For the same manufacturer I must sell to groups of 6 pieces of different products.

Is possible it?7

Thanks
Daniele

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Magento.SE!

This is possible utilizing the Qty Increment functionality in Magento. This is located in the inventory tab of the Catalog > Product management view.

[image]

Comment: Ok thanks, but is possible count quantity for manufacturer?
Example, I have the Manifacture 1 with 20 products and the Manifacture2 with 30 products. I'd like that the user buy any products but minimun 6 from same manifacture; ex 6 from Manifacture 1 and 12 from Manifacture 2.
I use Manifacture as an attribute of product